# Indenting code when redirecting text

Tags: bash

I would like to know if there is a solution to this issue.

In my shell script I have some code to redirect some text to a file:

```
if [ condition ]; then
   cat > /outputfile <<EOF
text123
text345
text456
EOF
fi
```

The problem is I want textxxx indented in my code, however if I do this then the redirected text would have spaces in it.

Is there a way I could indent the code nicely and have the output file without spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard answer is to use leading tabs (and they must be tabs, not blanks) and the `-` before the 'word':

```
cat <<-'EOF'
        Tab-indented text
    Blank-indented text
EOF
```

Which (if you have one or more actual tabs before 'Tab-indented') will output:

```
Tab-indented text
    Blank-indented text
```

If that's too inconvenient, then one alternative is to use `sed` instead of `cat`:

```
sed 's/^[     ]*//' <<EOF
    Randomly
        Indented
  Text
EOF
```

which will output:

```
Randomly
Indented
Text
```

(Again, you have to be sure that there are tabs in the right places; here, that means in the regular expression in the `sed` command.  Or you could use `sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//'` if you prefer.)

Note that the use of `'EOF'` vs `EOF` affects how the body of a here document is (or is not) interpreted. Compare:

```
cat <<-EOF
        $(rm -fr *)  # Do not try this at home! (Or at work.)
        $HOME
EOF
```

and

```
cat <<-'EOF'
        $(rm -fr *)
        $HOME
EOF
```

The first will have the shell recognize the `$(...)` notation and execute the command and substitute the output (nothing) into the here document.  Sorry about the work you've been doing over the last year or two!  Hope you've got good backups.  The second will treat the content of the script verbatim apart from removing leading tabs - which is safer, though any notation like `$(rm -fr *)` is not very safe!  The variable `$HOME` will be expanded in the first version; it will be left unchanged in the second.

Comment: One missing bit: quoting EOF effectively quotes the here document body; the original question had it unquoted.

Comment: @user2719058: true; I've fixed that oversight.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
cat<<-EOF
   text123
EOF
```

Comment: Note that the 'leading space' must be tabs.

Comment: Thanks it works, Some lines of text I have between the EOF are very long so I put line-breaks in there but it added tabs between them. Is there a way to avoid that? For example if you add \ after text123 and a line below it say text456. It will be on one line but there is a tab between them.

Comment: Regarding the long lines, I don't know a nice way to do that, but an ugly way is to replace the `cat` with something like `sed -e 's/^[\t]*//' -e '/\\$/{N;s/\\\n\t*//}'` (using \t requires GNU sed, I think).